# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor

Tags: c#, worker, asp.net-core-6.0

In ASP.NET Core 6, I am implementing Windows worker service using this code in the `Program.cs`:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        services.AddSingleton<DataContext>();

        services.AddHostedService<MyBackgoundTransactionConsumer>();

        services.AddSingleton<IMyTransactionRepository, IMyTransactionRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IQueueTransactionServices, QueueTransactionServices>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpProxyClient, HttpProxyClient>();

        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Logging.AddSerilog(_logger);

        builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

When I ran the Service, I got this error:

> System.AggregateException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: AppProcessor.Worker': Unable to resolve service for type 'Serilog.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'AppProcessor.Worker'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: AppProcessor.Services.MyTransactionConsumer'

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Serilog's [ASP.NET Core integration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) works over the 
[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) infrastructure, be sure to inject it, not `Serilog.ILogger`. For example (be sure to inject the generic one):

```cs
public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ...)
{
   ...
}
```